# How to get back index to dataframe as a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to get back my current index variable as a column variable. Is it possible?I tried using df.reset_index() but it did not work.Please click the link to view current version of fataframe

Ex:[Please Click here to view the current data frame. I want back "Date" as column variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8WkY.png)

Comment: `df = df.reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```py
df['new_column'] = df.index
```

It will copy the index as is, so if it's a datetime index then the new column will be a datetime column as well.